# React Native ListView: Prepend Items

Tags: listview, react-native

Is it possible to prepend items to React Native's ListView on an `onTopReached` event similar to the way one appends items on an `onEndReached` event? Currently, when I prepend rows to the list the ListView scrolls to the top.

The use case: I have an app with a feed the user can scroll down. When navigating away from the feed and then back to it I want to show the last seen row at the top. The user should then be able to scroll either up to see the previous rows she/he has scrolled passed and of course down to load new rows. Assuming I've already rendered the ListView starting from the last seen row a contrived example would look something like this:

```js
  _onTopReached() {
    this._unshiftRows();
  },

  _unshiftRows() {
    var list = this.props.list; // The entire list
    var lastSeenRowIndex = this.props.lastSeenRowIndex;
    var prevRows = list.slice(0, i);  
    this._rows = prevRows.concat(this._rows);
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this._rows)
    });
  },
```

In the example above I'm just prepending the first part of the list to the already rendered last part with `_onTopReached` firing right away because I'm already at the top. This however causes the ListView to re-render with the first row at the top of the screen rather than maintaining the previous position.

An alternative is to store the `y` offset of the last seen row and on navigating back to the ListView scroll to that position. However, that method requires every row before the current one to render which is time consuming. I've also not been able to get the correct offset with `scrollWithoutAnimationTo` or by setting `contentOffSet`. It does however scroll to the correct position if I use `scrollTo` or set a timeout before calling `scrollWithoutAnimationTo` and allow for the first rows to render in the mean time. But that's not very nice.

All help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I love react native, but the ListView I've also found really hard to get (fairly) simple things like this working well.. good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ben. The ListView has been a source of a lot frustration for me too.

Comment: Hey, were you ever able to figure this out? I have been able to get it to scroll to the appropriate position, but it momentarily shows the new content which is frustrating.

Comment: I ended up going another way about this which may not be relative to your problem. I wanted to navigate back to the feed in the state I left it in. So using the (controversial) Navigator component, I simply pop back to the feed scene rather than pushing it again on every routing event. That way the user is taken to the scene in the state it was left in. But that has nothing to do with the ListView per se. 

If you have fixed height items in your list you might want to look at [this](https://medium.com/chop-technologies/fast-and-fluid-infinite-list-with-react-native-336d010e51f2#.fihf4ifo2).

Comment: I'm also looking for clues how to resolve this. I'm using slice(0,20) when my user goes `up`and slice(-20) when my user goes down. However the CX is terrible since my components have different heights and I have no ideia how to scroll back the ListView to the correct position.

Comment: @ElliottBorealis did you implemented your own _onTopReached method? If so can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FlatList

Try adding the new items to the data source and use the 'scrolltoindex' method.

[FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex)

> scrollToIndex(params: object) 
>   Scrolls to the item at the specified index such that it is positioned in the viewable area such that viewPosition 0 places it at the top, 1 at the bottom, and 0.5 centered in the middle. viewOffset is a fixed number of pixels to offset the final target position.