# Scroll to a component is a Scrollview in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to be able to scroll a child component so that it visible on screen. How can I tell a react-native `ScrollView` or `ListView` to centre, or at least move to a certain component?

Comment: Use Flatlist and call the 'scrolltoindex' method [Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363480/react-native-listview-prepend-items/47168299#47168299)

Answer (score -2):

Both `ScrollView` and `ListView` have method `scrollTo`, so you can calculate position where you need to scroll

Comment: Well sure, but how do you calculate such a position?

Comment: You can use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout or  other methods to get position like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback

Comment: If you could add that to your answer, I can remove my downvote.  (Better yet, add a quick code sample, and I'll give it an upvote!)